# Where to place function declarations? VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm wondering where to place my function declarations in my project. For this project I am supposed to modularize the coding which currently lies under Button Calculate (previous project) but everytime I try to place it under button calculate it tells me it doesn't belong within the method body. So how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Function declarations should not be within another sub routine (example = ButtonCalculate_Click).  Instead you call the functions you create from ButtonCalculate_Click.  If you are to modularize it, it probably means you are to create a separate class, perhaps in a separate assembly,and put those functions there.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. I dont want to sound condescending at all in writing this, but I'm guessing that you're trying to put a function directly under a line of code that says something like..

```
private Sub ButtonCalculate()
```

This is the start of a subroutine definition. Try looking further down the code for the line that says..

```
End Sub
```

and put your function declaration  under there - leaving a blank line for readability's sake e.g.

```
private sub ButtonCalculate()
    'code for buttoncalculate
    'more code for buttoncalculate
    'lots more code for buttoncalculate
End Sub

private Function randomFunction(WhateverYourParametersare byval integer) as integer
    'your function code
    'more function code
End Function
```